# How can I know the effect of a weapon ability?

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

Most of the abilities are fairly straight forward, such as **Walking Speed +1**, but for some of them I have no idea what they mean, like **Shaking +1**. I assumed there would be someway to see a description of a weapon ability, but I'm unable to find anything in-game.

Is there anyway to see the description of a weapon ability, so I can see what it does?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no in-game explanation, but I found most of them pretty obvious based on things that happened to me during Solo. For example *Shaking* is when your aiming reticle starts shaking and jumping all over the screen.

There's an image floating around various message boards that does explain them all:

**Offensive**

- Shot range: Increase the distance your shots travel
- Shot homing: Increase the homing ability of weapons, if they have any to begin with
- Various attacks: Increase the power of that kind of attack
- In-peril attack boost: Raise attack when your health is low
- Full-health boost: Raise attack power when your health is full
- Shot cancellation: Increase ability to cancel incoming fire
- Power attack: Increase damage done by attack powers
- Item attack: Increase damage done by offensive items

**Defensive**

- Overall defense: Reduce the amount of damage received
- Melee defense: Reduce the amount of damage received from melee attacks
- Shot defense: Reduce the amount of damage received from ranged attacks
- Knockback defense: Reduce the chance of getting knocked down
- Evasion: Increase the size of your dodge window
- Health: Increase your max health
- In-peril autododge: When your health is low, you will sometimes automatically dodge

**Status Effects**

- Confusion: Causes reticle or movement to be inverted
- Petrification: Target turns to stone; they can't move and defense increases
- Freezing: Target is unable to move
- Paralysis: Target speed is reduced
- Shaking: Target's reticle goes haywire
- Burning: Small damage-over-time from fire
- Poison: Small damage-over-time from poison
- Weakening: Target's health max is halved
- Recovery effect: Status effects do not apply to you as long
- Status resistance: Status effects are less likely to apply to you

**Movement**

- Speed: Increases all movement speed
- Walking speed: Increases only walking speed
- Running speed: Increases only running speed
- Stamina: Increases the time you can run for

**Other**

- Self-injury: Your health is constantly draining, similar to poison.

Comment: I believe the "in-peril" effects apply when your health is below a certain amount, not just Crisis Mode. I think it's about a fifth (the point where Pit says "thanks" when you heal him out of it).